# Bash replace column of a csv based on identifier and replacement column from another CSV

Tags: bash

I have 2 CSV files, where the 1st one is my main CSV that contains all the columns I need. The 2nd CSV contains 2 columns, where the 1st column is an identifier, and the 2nd column is replacement value. For example

Main.csv

```
aaa 111 bbb 222 ccc 333
ddd 444 eee 555 fff 666
iii 777 jjj 888 kkk 999
lll 101 eee 201 nnn 301
```

replacement.csv

```
bbb abc
jjj def
eee ghi
```

I want the results to look like the following, where for example the 3rd column of the main.csv is the identifier and 1st column of the replacement.csv. By using that as an identifier, the 5th column of main.csv should be replaced with 2nd column of replacement.csv. Also, the main.csv can have repeated values, so all the values should be changed to the appropriate replacement value

```
aaa 111 bbb 222 abc 333
ddd 444 eee 555 ghi 666
iii 777 jjj 888 def 999
lll 101 eee 201 ghi 301
```

I tried a code like this

```
while read col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
do
    while read col7 col8
    do
        if[$col7==col3]
        then
            col5=col8
        fi
    done < RepCSV
done < MainCSV > MainCSV
```

But it did not work.
I'm quite new to bash, so the help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Atleast make an effort from your earlier question, rather than blatantly asking for code

Comment: Fair enough. I did not initially add the code I tried as I got nowhere with it. Added in an edit. Though the answer provided by @james Brown is more elegant and works, I would also like to know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                 # process the first file 
    a[$1]=$2              # hash $2 to a, $1 as key
    next                  # next record
}
{                         # second file
    $5=($3 in a?a[$3]:$5) ¤ replace $5 based on $3
}1' replacement main
aaa 111 bbb 222 abc 333
ddd 444 eee 555 ghi 666
iii 777 jjj 888 def 999
lll 101 eee 201 ghi 301
```